# How can I use PHP preg_match to capture string between and ignore all the outside of the two brackets?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have an example:

```
some text lorem ipsum ... {gallery}../2021/some_string_2021/some_other_string{/gallery} ... other lorem ipsum
```

And I need to get out only the `../2021/some_string_2021/some_other_string`.

How can I ignore all before `{gallery}` and all after `{/gallery}` while being able to capture `../2021/some_string_2021/some_other_string`?

Tried to figure it out but cannot make it work neither with some sort of combination with:

```
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);

if( preg_match( '!\(([^\)]+)\)!', $text2, $match ) )
echo $match[1];
```

Maybe I should first change [] to {}, and then try it with `(.*?){(.*?)}` ?

Comment: `preg_match('#(?<=\{gallery}).*?(?=\{/gallery})#', $str, $matches); echo $matches[0];`

Comment: For what it's worth...  The lookbehind in Nick's comment is more expensive than necessary.  `#\{gallery}\K.*?(?=\{/gallery})#` on the sample string will reduce the step count from 191 to 110.  Furthermore, capturing and referencing the opening tagname with `#\{(gallery)}\K.*?(?=\{/\1})#` will reduce the step count down to 107 while reducing the pattern length and eliminating the possible occurrence of typo-mismatching between the opening and closing tagname.